# web-application viewport problem

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, css

Please check out the screenshots, Its working ok in ipad but not in iphone/iphone4. What css/viewport settings I need to the page exactly fits inside the window (no-scrolling).

ipad screenshot
[image]

iphone4 screenshot
[image]

iphone screenshot
[image]

here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;user-scalability:no;">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Common/mobile.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>  

</head>

<body>
<div class="texture">
    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div id="eco-home-page" data-role="page" class="splash">
        <div data-role="content">           
            <a id="logo" href="#"><img width="100px" src="../Images/1.jpg" /></a>
            <div id="start-btns">
                <a href="#"><img src="../Images/1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="../Images/1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="../Images/1.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="../Images/1.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is css code

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {  
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 14px/16px Helvetica;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 2, center center, 750, from(#fafafa), to(#d5d5d5));
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center 45deg, circle closest-corner, #fafafa 0%, #d5d5d5 100%);  
}
a img {border: none; }
.texture {
    background: url("../Images/texture.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

.splash {
    background: url(../Images/shapes1.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#eco-home-page a#logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -400px;
    position: absolute;
}
#eco-home-page #start-btns {width: 610px; height: 406px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -300px; margin-top: -200px;}
#eco-home-page .splash-screen a#logo {margin-top: -320px !important; }



/*for ipad*/
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        // extra styles for mobile
    }
}

/*for iphone/ipod*/
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        // extra styles for desktop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css set the widths of #start-btns and #logo as a percentage. Then change the width of the body depending on the device you're using (i.e. in the media queries). In the iphone's case this would be 'width: 320px;'

You'll have to change the positioning technique of these elements as absolute positioning with fixed negative margins will no longer work. You could try putting 'text-align: center;' on the body with 'margin: 0 auto;' on #start-btns and #logo.

It would be advisable to change most if not all widths to percentages (or some other relative measure such as ems). That way you only need to change the body's width (or font size) inside the media query and your layout will automatically change.

Something like below should do it.

```
html {height: 100%;}
body {  
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 14px/16px Helvetica;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 2, center center, 750, from(#fafafa), to(#d5d5d5));
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(center center 45deg, circle closest-corner, #fafafa 0%, #d5d5d5 100%);  
    text-align: center;
}
a img {border: none; }

.texture {
    background: url("../Images/texture.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

.splash {
    background: url(../Images/shapes1.png) no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#eco-home-page a#logo img {
    margin: 6.5% auto;  
    width: 13%;
}

#eco-home-page #start-btns {
    width: 80%; 
    height: auto;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#eco-home-page #start-btns img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5%;
    width: 49%;
}

/*for ipad*/
@media all and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        width: 768px;
    }
}

/*for iphone/ipod*/
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

Comment: % will work. I've just tried it with your code example above... you'll also need to add 'position: relative;' to the 'body' rule in the media query (or to one of the ancestors of #start-btns) due to the 'position: absolute;'. Don't forget the width:320px declaration.

Comment: also the media queries may need to be the other way round. max-width for iphone and min-width for ipad

Comment: I've added some tweaks for the css to my original answer. Thinking about it you probably don't even need the media queries as all widths are in %s so the layouts should adjust fine to the various device widths